# How to import a file present in a different folder inside a folder

Tags: reactjs, react-native, import, react-redux, export

I'm confused with file imports and exports in react.

I have a `components` folder. Inside that, I have an `Authentication` folder in which there is `Login.css`. Outside the components folder, I have a `pages` folder inside it there is `Login.js`. How can I import `Login.css` to `Login.js`

```
|
|_> components
| |_> Authentication
|   |_> Login.css
|_> pages
  |_> Login.js
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
---pages
    -Login.js
---components
  ---Authentication
    -Login.css
```

I am guessing this is your folder structure. To import Login.css to your Login.js file, you need to add,

```
import "../components/Authentication/Login.css"
```

at the top of your Login.js file.

`..` to traverse up your directory

`.` is at your current directory

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you should improve the quality of your question. You have many typos and it is hard to understand the structure of your files. is this correct?:

```
Project
├── pages
│   └── Login.js
└── components
    └── Authentication
         └── Login.css
```

If so inside Login.js import it like that:

```
import '../components/authentication/login.css';
```

But why are you separating your files like that?
As Login seems to be a page, I think it does not make sense to put its style sheet into components/Authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Importing and exporting can be done in two ways:

1. Default Export/Import
2. Named Export/Import

**1) Default Exports**

You can have *only single default export per file*

Lets suppose you have a file named `yourComponent.js` and code inside it is following

```
const YourComponent = () => {
    ...
    return <>...</>
}

export default YourComponent;
```

Suppose you want that component in `index.js`, you can import `YourComponent`in the following way:

```
import YourComponent from "./yourComponent"
//in case the index file and yourComponent file are adjacent to each other

import YourComponent from "./folder/yourComponent"
//in case the index file and folder are adjacent to each other and folder has yourComponent

import YourComponent from "../yourComponent"
//in case yourComponent file is one level up from the index file
```

**2) Named Exports**

You can have *multiple named exports from single file*

This is how you will perform a named export of `YourComponent`

```
export const YourComponent = () => {
     ...
     return <>...</>
}
```

You have to enter the same name by which you have exported the component in case of named export. This is how you import a named export

```
import {YourComponent} from "./yourComponent"
```